# Using NSUserDefaults with multiple xibs

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have been following a tutorial on creating an iPhone app with multiple xibs. The tutorial describes putting all the code in the View file, rather than the View Controller.

I am now looking at using NSDefaults to save a setting from my app's options screen, and then display it again when the user goes back into the options screen. The problem is though, the setting is not getting loaded back in.

In my appdelegate.h file i have got:

```
NSInteger gMaxDistance;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger gMaxDistance;
```

In my appdelegate.m file i have got:

```
@synthesize gMaxDistance;
```

In my OptionsView.m i have got:

```
NSUserDefaults *AppSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[AppSettings setInteger:(int)distanceSlider.value forKey:@"MaxDistance"];
[AppSettings synchronize];
```

How do i correctly recall this value and where does the code need to go?

If i put it in the OptionsViewController.m viewDidLoad method, the compiler complains that it can't find distanceSlider.

If i put it in the OptionsView.m file (where all my objects are found) in the initWithFrame method, nothing happens.

Please help, this has tied me in knots all day!!!

Comment: Just a quick note: by convention, variables like appSettings should be named in camelCase, i.e with the first letter in lowercase.

Comment: I appreciate the advice about variable naming. I'll take that on board !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get is by doing

```
NSUserDefaults *appSettings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int recalledDistance = [appSettings integerForKey@"MaxDistance"];
```

And you can do it from any viewController.

Comment: So if i load the recalledDistance from the NSDefaults object, where do i then set the slider or other visual control to display the value? I tried putting it in the initWithFrame method in the View (rather than the ViewController), but the control did not show the recalled value.